# Using external library with Nashorn Javascript Engine

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, nashorn

I try to use Google Maps Api with Nashorn. But it seems that it doesn't recognize the api.

**Bean**

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");

engine.eval(new FileReader(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResource("/resources/js/MapGoogle/functions.js").getFile()));

Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;

Object result = invocable.invokeFunction("myFunction","param1");
```

**functions.js**

```
var myFunction = function(param1) {

   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

   return "";
};
```

**Error:**

```
javax.el.ELException: javax.script.ScriptException: 
ReferenceError: "google" is not defined in <eval> at line number 9
```

How can I add this library so that Nashorn can work with Google Maps Api?

Comment: Do you get any errors when you evaluate that external file?

Comment: @ Vivin Paliath, absolutely no errors from the functions.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest replacing this line:

`var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();`

with the following line:

`var directionsService = new Packages.google.maps.DirectionsService();`

As the class package is neither "com", "org", or "java", you need to add "Packages." as a prefix for Nashorn to call the java library properly.

And obviously you need to have it in your classpath...

Comment: My solution is valid only if the API mentioned is included in a java library.

Apparently for Google Maps API you need to include this js script:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js)

Last but not least: you need an API key...

Comment: After a quick reverse on the google api, it seems this can only work in a web client, not in Nashorn. The above mentioned file includes 'window' (equivalent of global namespace) and 'document' (the DOM). There is no DOM in Nashorn...

Comment: Have a look there too [https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/mapsengine/v1](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/mapsengine/v1) for a pure java library. This has more chances to work with Nashorn.